# How should I give the class itself to a boost::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have the following code which raises an error about line `m_threads.push_back(boost::thread(boost::ref(*this)));`. Could you help me the figure out what is wrong?

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>  // NOLINT(readability/streams)
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
#include "boost/thread/barrier.hpp"
#include "boost/atomic.hpp"
// #include "gflags/gflags.h"
// #include "glog/logging.h"

// #include "caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h"
// #include "caffe/util/db.hpp"
// #include "caffe/util/io.hpp"
// #include "caffe/util/rng.hpp"

using namespace caffe;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)
using std::pair;
using boost::scoped_ptr;

DEFINE_bool(gray, false,
    "When this option is on, treat images as grayscale ones");
DEFINE_bool(shuffle, false,
    "Randomly shuffle the order of images and their labels");
DEFINE_int32(threads, 1,
    "Build DB using multiple threads.");
DEFINE_string(backend, "lmdb",
        "The backend {lmdb, leveldb} for storing the result");
DEFINE_int32(resize_width, 0, "Width images are resized to");
DEFINE_int32(resize_height, 0, "Height images are resized to");
DEFINE_bool(check_size, false,
    "When this option is on, check that all the datum have the same size");
DEFINE_bool(encoded, false,
    "When this option is on, the encoded image will be save in datum");
DEFINE_string(encode_type, "",
    "Optional: What type should we encode the image as ('png','jpg',...).");


class ThreadedReader
{
public:
  typedef struct {
    int line_id;
    bool status;
    Datum datum;
  } data_entry;

  ThreadedReader(int threads, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> >& lines,
    const string& encode_type, const string& root_folder,
    int resize_height, int resize_width, bool is_color) :
    m_thread_count(threads), m_lines(lines),
    m_barrier_read(threads), m_barrier_fetch(2),
    m_id(0), m_thd_done(0),
    m_done(false),
    m_root_folder(root_folder),
    m_encode_type(encode_type),
    m_resize_height(resize_height), m_resize_width(resize_width),
    m_is_color(is_color)
  {
    m_data.resize(m_thread_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
      m_threads.push_back(boost::thread(boost::ref(*this)));
  }

  ~ThreadedReader() {
    // for (int i = 0; i < m_thread_count; ++i)
      // m_threads[i].join();
  }

  void operator()()
  {
    for (;;) {
      int my_id = m_id.fetch_add(1, boost::memory_order_acq_rel);
      const int my_base = my_id % m_thread_count;

      m_barrier_read.count_down_and_wait();

      m_data[my_base].status = false;
      m_data[my_base].line_id = my_id;

      if (my_id < m_lines.size()) {
        m_data[my_base].line_id = my_id;
        m_data[my_base].status = ReadImageToDatum(m_root_folder + m_lines[my_id].first,
          m_lines[my_id].second, m_resize_height, m_resize_width, m_is_color,
          m_encode_type, &m_data[my_base].datum);
      }

      if (m_thd_done.fetch_add(1, boost::memory_order_acq_rel) + 1 == m_thread_count) {
        m_barrier_fetch.count_down_and_wait();
        m_thd_done.store(0, boost::memory_order_release);
        if (m_id.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed) >= m_lines.size())
          m_done.store(true);
        m_barrier_fetch.count_down_and_wait();
      }

      if (m_id.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed) >= m_lines.size())
        break;
    }
  }

  // bool fetch_batch(std::vector<data_entry>& vec)
  // {
  //   using std::swap;

  //   if (m_done.load(boost::memory_order_acquire))
  //     return false;

  //   m_barrier_fetch.count_down_and_wait();
  //   swap(vec, m_data);
  //   if (m_data.size() < m_thread_count)
  //     m_data.resize(m_thread_count);
  //   m_barrier_fetch.count_down_and_wait();

  //   return true;
  // }

private:
  const int m_thread_count;
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> >& m_lines;

  boost::barrier m_barrier_read;
  boost::barrier m_barrier_fetch;
  boost::atomic<int> m_id;
  boost::atomic<int> m_thd_done;
  boost::atomic<bool> m_done;

  const std::string& m_root_folder;
  const std::string& m_encode_type;
  const int m_resize_height, m_resize_width;
  const bool m_is_color;

  std::vector<data_entry> m_data;
  std::vector<boost::thread> m_threads;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  return 0;
}
```

The errror:

```
passing ‘const boost::thread’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘boost::thread::operator boost::detail::thread_move_t<boost::thread>()’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
make: *** [.build_release/tools/convert_imageset_threaded.o] Error 1
```

Comment: Are you perhaps creating a *const* `ThreadedReader` object? Please show how you use this class, preferably create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us.

Comment: The code you link to (please don't do that! Edit your question to include a MCVE instead) is not the same as the one you show in the question. Really, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to include it.

Comment: now it is same http://pastebin.com/MKHJ0bcN . there is only class definition placed above. If you run the linked code you will see the same error

Answer (score 0):

Your code compiles. It should just be a lot more reduced.

The error message indicates that in your real code you have a const/volatile qualified ThreadedReader, perhaps.

And you shouldn't mix signed/unsigned integers in comparison.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac690818c7916f60)</kbd>**

```
// This program converts a set of images to a lmdb/leveldb by storing them
// as Datum proto buffers.
// Usage:
//   convert_imageset [FLAGS] ROOTFOLDER/ LISTFILE DB_NAME
//
// where ROOTFOLDER is the root folder that holds all the images, and LISTFILE
// should be a list of files as well as their labels, in the format as
//   subfolder1/file1.JPEG 7
//   ....

#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>  // NOLINT(readability/streams)
#include <string>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include "boost/scoped_ptr.hpp"
#include "boost/thread.hpp"
#include "boost/thread/barrier.hpp"
#include "boost/atomic.hpp"
// #include "gflags/gflags.h"
// #include "glog/logging.h"

// #include "caffe/proto/caffe.pb.h"
// #include "caffe/util/db.hpp"
// #include "caffe/util/io.hpp"
// #include "caffe/util/rng.hpp"

//using namespace caffe;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)
using std::pair;
using boost::scoped_ptr;

struct Datum {};

class ThreadedReader
{
public:
  typedef struct {
    int line_id;
    bool status;
    Datum datum;
  } data_entry;

  bool ReadImageToDatum(...) { return false; }

  ThreadedReader(int threads, std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> >& lines,
    const std::string& encode_type, const std::string& root_folder,
    int resize_height, int resize_width, bool is_color) :
    m_thread_count(threads), m_lines(lines),
    m_barrier_read(threads), m_barrier_fetch(2),
    m_id(0), m_thd_done(0),
    m_done(false),
    m_root_folder(root_folder),
    m_encode_type(encode_type),
    m_resize_height(resize_height), m_resize_width(resize_width),
    m_is_color(is_color)
  {
    m_data.resize(m_thread_count);
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; ++i)
      m_threads.push_back(boost::thread(boost::ref(*this)));
  }

  ~ThreadedReader() {
    // for (int i = 0; i < m_thread_count; ++i)
      // m_threads[i].join();
  }

  void operator()()
  {
    for (;;) {
      unsigned my_id = m_id.fetch_add(1, boost::memory_order_acq_rel);
      const int my_base = my_id % m_thread_count;

      m_barrier_read.count_down_and_wait();

      m_data[my_base].status = false;
      m_data[my_base].line_id = my_id;

      if (my_id < m_lines.size()) {
        m_data[my_base].line_id = my_id;
        m_data[my_base].status = ReadImageToDatum(m_root_folder + m_lines[my_id].first,
          m_lines[my_id].second, m_resize_height, m_resize_width, m_is_color,
          m_encode_type, &m_data[my_base].datum);
      }

      if (m_thd_done.fetch_add(1, boost::memory_order_acq_rel) + 1 == m_thread_count) {
        m_barrier_fetch.count_down_and_wait();
        m_thd_done.store(0, boost::memory_order_release);
        if (m_id.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed) >= m_lines.size())
          m_done.store(true);
        m_barrier_fetch.count_down_and_wait();
      }

      if (m_id.load(boost::memory_order_relaxed) >= m_lines.size())
        break;
    }
  }

  // bool fetch_batch(std::vector<data_entry>& vec)
  // {
  //   using std::swap;

  //   if (m_done.load(boost::memory_order_acquire))
  //     return false;

  //   m_barrier_fetch.count_down_and_wait();
  //   swap(vec, m_data);
  //   if (m_data.size() < m_thread_count)
  //     m_data.resize(m_thread_count);
  //   m_barrier_fetch.count_down_and_wait();

  //   return true;
  // }

private:
  const int m_thread_count;
  std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> >& m_lines;

  boost::barrier m_barrier_read;
  boost::barrier m_barrier_fetch;
  boost::atomic<unsigned> m_id;
  boost::atomic<int> m_thd_done;
  boost::atomic<bool> m_done;

  const std::string& m_root_folder;
  const std::string& m_encode_type;
  const int m_resize_height, m_resize_width;
  const bool m_is_color;

  std::vector<data_entry> m_data;
  std::vector<boost::thread> m_threads;

};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
//   ::google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);

// #ifndef GFLAGS_GFLAGS_H_
//   namespace gflags = google;
// #endif

//   gflags::SetUsageMessage("Convert a set of images to the leveldb/lmdb\n"
//         "format used as input for Caffe.\n"
//         "Usage:\n"
//         "    convert_imageset [FLAGS] ROOTFOLDER/ LISTFILE DB_NAME\n"
//         "The ImageNet dataset for the training demo is at\n"
//         "    http://www.image-net.org/download-images\n");
//   gflags::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);

//   if (argc < 4) {
//     gflags::ShowUsageWithFlagsRestrict(argv[0], "tools/convert_imageset");
//     return 1;
//   }

//   const bool is_color = !FLAGS_gray;
//   const int threads = FLAGS_threads > 1 ? FLAGS_threads : 1;
//   const bool check_size = FLAGS_check_size;
//   const bool encoded = FLAGS_encoded;
//   const string encode_type = FLAGS_encode_type;

//   std::ifstream infile(argv[2]);
//   std::vector<std::pair<std::string, int> > lines;
//   std::string filename;
//   int label;
//   while (infile >> filename >> label) {
//     lines.push_back(std::make_pair(filename, label));
//   }
//   if (FLAGS_shuffle) {
//     // randomly shuffle data
//     LOG(INFO) << "Shuffling data";
//     shuffle(lines.begin(), lines.end());
//   }
//   LOG(INFO) << "A total of " << lines.size() << " images.";

//   if (encode_type.size() && !encoded)
//     LOG(INFO) << "encode_type specified, assuming encoded=true.";

//   int resize_height = std::max<int>(0, FLAGS_resize_height);
//   int resize_width = std::max<int>(0, FLAGS_resize_width);

//   // Create new DB
//   scoped_ptr<db::DB> db(db::GetDB(FLAGS_backend));
//   db->Open(argv[3], db::NEW);
//   scoped_ptr<db::Transaction> txn(db->NewTransaction());

//   // Storing to db
//   std::string root_folder(argv[1]);
//   int count = 0;
//   const int kMaxKeyLength = 256;
//   char key_cstr[kMaxKeyLength];
//   int data_size = 0;
//   bool data_size_initialized = false;

//   if (threads > 1) {
//     ThreadedReader rdr(threads, lines, encode_type, root_folder,
//       resize_height, resize_width, is_color);

//     std::vector<ThreadedReader::data_entry> vec;
//     while (rdr.fetch_batch(vec)) {
//       for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
//         if (!vec[i].status)
//           continue;

//         if (check_size) {
//           if (!data_size_initialized) {
//             data_size = vec[i].datum.channels() * vec[i].datum.height() * vec[i].datum.width();
//             data_size_initialized = true;
//           } else {
//             const std::string& data = vec[i].datum.data();
//             CHECK_EQ(data.size(), data_size) << "Incorrect data field size "
//               << data.size();
//           }
//         }

//         // sequential
//         int length = snprintf(key_cstr, kMaxKeyLength, "%08d_%s", vec[i].line_id,
//           lines[vec[i].line_id].first.c_str());

//         // Put in db
//         string out;
//         CHECK(vec[i].datum.SerializeToString(&out));
//         txn->Put(string(key_cstr, length), out);

//         if (++count % 1000 == 0) {
//           // Commit db
//           txn->Commit();
//           txn.reset(db->NewTransaction());
//           LOG(ERROR) << "Processed " << count << " files.";
//         }

//       }
//     }
//   } else {
//     Datum datum;
//     for (int line_id = 0; line_id < lines.size(); ++line_id) {
//       bool status;
//       std::string enc = encode_type;
//       if (encoded && !enc.size()) {
//         // Guess the encoding type from the file name
//         string fn = lines[line_id].first;
//         size_t p = fn.rfind('.');
//         if (p == fn.npos)
//           LOG(WARNING) << "Failed to guess the encoding of '" << fn << "'";
//         enc = fn.substr(p);
//         std::transform(enc.begin(), enc.end(), enc.begin(), ::tolower);
//       }
//       status = ReadImageToDatum(root_folder + lines[line_id].first,
//         lines[line_id].second, resize_height, resize_width, is_color,
//         enc, &datum);
//       if (status == false) continue;
//       if (check_size) {
//         if (!data_size_initialized) {
//           data_size = datum.channels() * datum.height() * datum.width();
//           data_size_initialized = true;
//         } else {
//           const std::string& data = datum.data();
//           CHECK_EQ(data.size(), data_size) << "Incorrect data field size "
//             << data.size();
//         }
//       }
//       // sequential
//       int length = snprintf(key_cstr, kMaxKeyLength, "%08d_%s", line_id,
//         lines[line_id].first.c_str());

//       // Put in db
//       string out;
//       CHECK(datum.SerializeToString(&out));
//       txn->Put(string(key_cstr, length), out);

//       if (++count % 1000 == 0) {
//         // Commit db
//         txn->Commit();
//         txn.reset(db->NewTransaction());
//         LOG(ERROR) << "Processed " << count << " files.";
//       }
//     }
//   }
//   // write the last batch
//   if (count % 1000 != 0) {
//     txn->Commit();
//     LOG(ERROR) << "Processed " << count << " files.";
//   }
  return 0;
}
```